# How to shift moderncv cventry description to the left?

Tags: moderncv

I'd like to shift the description of a `moderncv` entry (here the "Lorem ipsum..." block created with `\blindtext` in command `\cventry`) to the left, positioning it under the date and keeping it left aligned, like the date. What's the best way to do that?

[image]

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{familyname}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{\raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}}{\raggedright\hintstyle{#2}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\cventry{2013--2014}{Title}{Subtitle}{Subsubtitle}{Subsubsubtitle}{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the design of command `\cventry` does not allow what you want because it defines a table and only the first parameter (`2013--2014` for example) is placed in the first column.

But there is a workaround.  Define a new command

```
% usage: \mycvitem{Text}
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[2][.25em]{%
  \vspace{-.25em}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}%
    \small#2%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

to insert the text over the complete textwidth.  Just leave in `cventry` the last parameter empty.  Then the combination

```
\cventry{2013--2014}{Title}{Subtitle}{Subsubtitle}{Subsubsubtitle}{}
\mycvitem{\blindtext}
```

gives the output you want.

See the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\firstname{firstname}
\familyname{familyname}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{\raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}}{\raggedright\hintstyle{#2}}{}{}

% usage: \mycvitem{Text}
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[2][.25em]{%
  \vspace{-.25em}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}%
    \small#2%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\cventry{2013--2014}{Title}{Subtitle}{Subsubtitle}{Subsubsubtitle}{\blindtext}

\cventry{2013--2014}{Title}{Subtitle}{Subsubtitle}{Subsubsubtitle}{} % <=====
\mycvitem{\blindtext} % <====================================================
\end{document}
```

with the result

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for taking the time!